# Can a JBOSS 7+ servlet listen/take over another subdeployment's requests?

Tags: java, jboss

Currently working an application that is moving from JBOSS 4 (java 6) to JBOSS 7.1 (Java 8). It had no REST WS - only SOAP and worked with Servlets.

I added my WAR containing a basic REST Service (ApplicationPath class with 1 resource class and a web.xml (empty since I'm using RESTEasy implementation which should scan my classes)) to the main EAR. 
During deployment, I see no errors in my logs and it says my .war has been deployed and my web context registered.

However, whenever I call one of my resource's endpoint I get the default JBOSS response for Error 404 Not Found (the url is correct though) and when I try to call the same URL but by using PUT or POST I get the message "Http Method POST is not supported by this URL" which is typically an error from Custom Servlets.

Is it possible that another Servlet is listening to my path or taking over things? Even if outside of my web context? How could I investigate/debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the old RESTeasy Version - 3.0.7-Final that was being used, which has some known bugs with the `@ApplicationPath` annotation and web.xml configuration. After using the provided version of RESTeasy from the JBOSS 7 (version 3.6.1-SP2), everything worked like a charm.